# javascript or jquery timer (with stop,resume,reset functions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

i was wondering if anyone knows where can i find an already coded javascript/jquery timer which has the following properties:

- start timer
- stop timer
- reset timer

i just have a div in my web app, in which am diplaying text of a timer, but the timer i currently have bugs a lot because :

the timer is displayed on a dashboard. i designed the dashboard using javascript/jquery and this dashboard auto refreshes at an interval ( i did "set_interval blabla").
So i was trying to display a timer counting down at precisely the same timing of the javascript interval ( which refreshes the dashboard), so i had to code in a way to synchronize the javascript interval timer and the display timer that i coded . But it still bugs and at some points the display timer grows exponentially.

i want to know if there is a timer which has the properties i mentionned above OR if it is possible to DISPLAY the minutes/seconds of the "set_interval" interval timer that refreshes my dashboard?

thanks a lot:)

Comment: Let's see some actual code. What's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a jquery plugin:

http://jquery.offput.ca/every/

It might be helpful